# Renderscript: first two runs with "No GC methods" - afterwards ok

Tags: android, methods, garbage-collection, renderscript

I wrote an image processing app that uses several complex Renderscript kernels. The app works perfect on my Galaxy Tab 2 (4.2) and Samsung S5 (5.0). I also runs through on my Sony Xperia M2 (4.3), but for some reasons the first two runs give a message

```
 E/RenderScript_jni﹕ No GC methods
```

(while still running through). Then, in the third and following runs it doesn't show that message anymore. The problem is that the numerical result I get in the first two runs is slightly different from the result in the following runs (these are definitly correct and match with the results on the other two devices).

Any idea what the problem could be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to isolate the calls that cause this message in order to make sure that difference in results and the message are not a coincidence? As the next step you could describe the expected and actual results in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Any chances you are creating and using an Allocation without copying from an array? I had problems with assuming an Allocation was created initialized with zeros but on some devices that was not true. I could not find in the documentation if that's supposed to be device dependent, but it's one way your results could be flaky in some runs. If that's the case try copying an initialized array into the Allocation.

Comment: Regular Allocations are not zero-initialized. They do need to be manually initialized before use.

Comment: First it is not a severe problem, thus I have not yet investigated deeper - but will do so later, excatly the way Miloslaw proposed. I am sure this will be easy to solve. Generally I am more than happy with Renderscript an tested it on many devices and virtually all APIs >=17 now.